# Add viewcontroller for iOS app using F#

Tags: ios, visual-studio, f#, visual-studio-mac

I just downloaded VS 2017 for MAC trying to build my iOS using Xamarin.

With C# things sounds fine, but with F# things are not ok I can not create new `viecontroller` and can not assign any action for the elements in the only `viewcontroller` that generated automatically at startup.

This is the screen I got while trying to generate another `viewcontroller` using `F#`

[image]

And this is the screen I got while working with `C#`

[image]